# Java Bytecode Optimisation

Tags: java, bytecode

Below is the Java bytecode,

```
0: iconst_1
1: istore_1
2: iload_1
3: ...
```

I can optimize it to

```
0: iconst_1
1: ...
```

However, I am wondering is this always safe or when we can make sure this optimization is safe?

Comment: How is you second code snippet different from the first?

Comment: Quite unclear what you optimized it to and how. Also, provide code if you want to know if it's safe.

Comment: There is no difference two codes.what is your question? please post your question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This optimization is *not* safe if somewhere in the method code another `iload_1` instruction exists.

More important, this manual optimization has no sense. The JIT compiler easily clean out excessive data assignments itself, so the original code and "optimized" code would yield the same machine code after compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The JIT looks for set patterns generated by the compiler and optimises those.  If you manually generate or alter code you have to make sure you are not producing code which appears simpler to you but cannot be as easily optimised by the JIT i.e. resulting in slower execution.

As @Alexei says, its not safe, and I suspect its not faster but could be slower.